# ProgressBar Theme with diagonal lines decorator

Tags: wpf, coding-style, progress-bar

I want to decorate the WPF ProgressBar like the image below:

**Current**:

[image: ProgressBar without decoration]

**Decorated**:

[image: ProgressBar with decoration]

Also, those blank diagonal lines should move in marquee animation from left to right. At the moment i have this simple Style for the current appearance:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ProgressBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Border x:Name="BorderBackground" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ProgressBarBorderBrush}" Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarBackgroundBrush}">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Determinate" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="PART_Track" Margin="2" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" />
                        <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator" Margin="2" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarTrackBackgroundBrush}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Anyone can help me to get it? I searched for it but maybe i missed the correct keywords to find something like this, at least i usually see (like at OS X progressbar) that this "decoration" is usually used.

Thanks in advance ;).

---

**Solution template with the answer code a bit modified:**

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ProgressBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Border x:Name="BorderBackground" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ProgressBarBorderBrush}" Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarBackgroundBrush}" Effect="{StaticResource LightStrongDownLinearShadowEffect}">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Determinate" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="PART_Track" Margin="2" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" />
                        <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator" Margin="2" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarTrackBackgroundBrush}" ClipToBounds="True">
                            <Border x:Name="DiagonalDecorator" Width="5000">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Stretch="None" Viewbox="0,0,1,1" Viewport="0,0,25,25" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                                        <DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                                        </DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#20FFFFFF" Geometry="M10,0 22,0 12,25 0,22 Z" />
                                        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    </DrawingBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <Border.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" From="0" To=".25" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:15" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </Border.Triggers>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Please, beware that a Progress Bar with animations and gradients might be counter productive; it will cost CPU time when you are already waiting for something...

Comment: Hmmm, i didnt saw any performance issues testing it. If i see something, ill post it. Thanks for the advice ;)

Comment: The Windows Phone progress bar is famous for consuming too much power: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/

Comment: Would you mind posting the brushes if you still have them after all this time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/progress/ProgressODoom.aspx) article from codeproject.com has a working version of the "barber pole" progress bar.  Search the article for "CandyCaneProgressPainter".

**Previous answer:**

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wpf/thread/8aee5dff-b0f8-4434-8e2e-f6e7b187f951) does almost exactly what you want.  All you have to do to make it what you want is restrict the visibility of the rectangle to the percentage you want and change the height/width ratio.

The keywords you want are "storyboard", "animate" and "trigger"

Here is the xaml from the link with some comments from the link on making the animation smooth:

```
 <Rectangle x:Name="pole" Width="100" Height="20" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
  <Rectangle.Fill>
   <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Stretch="None" Viewbox="0,0,1,1" Viewport="0,0,25,25" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
    <DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
     <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
    </DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
     <GeometryDrawing Brush="Red" Geometry="M10,0 25,0 15,25 0,25 Z" />    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
   </DrawingBrush>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
  <Rectangle.Triggers>
   <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
    <BeginStoryboard>
     <Storyboard>
      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" From="0" To=".25" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:1" />
     </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
   </EventTrigger>
  </Rectangle.Triggers>
 </Rectangle>
```

> I guess the jerking happens if you remove the "width" value, but if the value is put back it runs smooth. Weird.
>
> Yup, indeed it basically needed a few adjustments with the multiples of the number rules the width in this case the animation can be a .1 or a .05 if for instance you have a 5000 width.... now it work great!

Comment: The codeproject article was great, but its for winforms. Nevermind, its a nice one ;).

I used your first answer to do what i wanted, and it works pretty well with few adjustments. Used a 5.000 width as they said, and adjusts the duration to make it smooth. Also mark the property ClipToBounds = True of the parent element.

Thanks!

PD: Ill write the template with the solution at question post.

Comment: Hmmm, thought it was.  Oh well, guess I'll remove it then.  For what its worth, winforms controls can be hosted in wpf.

Answer (score 3):

In your PART_Indicator border embed a Compound Path of the shapes to make the diagonal lines. You're going to have to kind of fake the Marquee effect to get the scrolling diagonal lines however unless you want to use a jquery plugin or other alternative.

However what you CAN do in pure xaml is create the diagonal line paths, make lots and lots of them to make the row of diagnol lines very very long. Since they're embedded in the indicator border they're only visible within it.

Now create a new storyboard animation and use a ControlStoryboardAction Behavior to trigger it onload and set it to repeat. Grab the diagonal lines compound path an choose a keyframe on your timeline a ways out from the start frame, then drag the Compound Path of diagonal lines to one side or set a large Margin to the left so during the animation sequence it moves to the right. The idea is its a visual hoax. Your diagonal lines will just act as an animation storyboard that only mimics the marquee animation. So those lines will still move across the bar and hopefully theres enough of them the animation doesnt repeat before the content is loaded. Hopefully this makes sense haha. It takes some tweaking but you can result in a decent solution. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks! Finally made out with Mydogisbox answer, but your idea was correct ;)

Comment: No worries as long as you got your answer, I didn't notice the other when I posted. Merry Christmas! :)

Answer (score 1):

This post is quite old, but I just faced the same problem and got a nice solution I would like to share:

```
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBarBackgroundBrush" Color="Gray" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBarTrackBackgroundBrush" Color="#105295" />
  <Style x:Key="{x:Type ProgressBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                        <controls:RoundBorder x:Name="BorderBackground" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="0"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource ProgressBarBorderBrush}"
                        Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarBackgroundBrush}">
                            <Grid>
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Determinate" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <Border x:Name="PART_Track" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="3"  />
                                <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarTrackBackgroundBrush}" ClipToBounds="True">
                                    <Border x:Name="DiagonalDecorator" Width="5000">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <DrawingBrush  TileMode="Tile" Stretch="None" Viewbox="0,0,1,1" Viewport="0,0,36,34"  ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                                                <DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                                    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                                                </DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#156dc7" Geometry="M0,0 18,0 36,34 18,34 Z" />
                                                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                            </DrawingBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <Border.Triggers>
                                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                                    From="0" To=".36" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:18" />
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </EventTrigger>
                                        </Border.Triggers>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </controls:RoundBorder >
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Excellent work.  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @thardes2 can you please provide a complete version of the xaml document of your answer? Because when I copy paste the whole answer I get an XAML error (value of type Style cannot be added in UIElementCollection). Note that I put your code inside a grid.

Comment: @NikSp - I am sorry, I don't have access to that snipped anymore

Comment: @thardes2 it's ok. I am experimenting with fancy stuff in C#. Thanks for the notice.